# Angular iterator in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a Json objects, which contains one field with date, I need to take it and prepare for other processing, but I don't know how to take just one field from one object, I tried to do that:

```
app.controller('timerCtrl', function ($scope) {
   var endDate =  $scope.data.list[1].end;// but list[1] prints just list[1].ends value, but how can i get and prepare the fields of other objects?
});
```

Json-object:

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "New shop",
    "shop": "DNS",
    "begin": "09-05-2017",
    "end":" 12-05-2017"

},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "New shop",
    "shop": "M-video",
    "begin":"05-05-2017",
    "end":"15-05-2017"
}
```

]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the list like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.list.length; i++){
    var endDate =  $scope.data.list[i].end;
}
```

Alternatively, you could get an array of the dates by maping them to another array like this.  Then, you could pass that on for further processing, depending on what you're doing.

```
 var endDates = $scope.data.list.map(function(listItem) { return listItem.end; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question will probably close, but here's the 'angular iterator' way to do it as you asked:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Enjoy bombarding your stack if you have a large json.

Or you can always treat it like just another array and use a for loop.